# What should be done with questions that are duplicates if they get migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration

I'm thinking of this question:

https://serverfault.com/questions/275767/how-can-i-download-the-correct-sound-driver-for-my-window-xp

It's a textbook "Belongs on Superuser" question, but if it were migrated, it'd be a duplicate.  The question that Ignacio quoted in his answer is virtually identical (and has a good answer from Ignacio.)

I voted to migrate, but then a second later I wished I could change my vote to simply close.  I know it's still off-topic here, but I think the "damage" by having an off-topic question here is less overall than moving it, then having it closed as a duplicate there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's a crap question here AND it's a crap question there, I just vote to close.

If it's a crap question here AND it's a good question there, I vote to migrate.

If it's a crap question here AND it's a good question there and I KNOW it's a dupe there, I vote to close, but always add a comment to say "Closing as it's a dupe of {x}"

Comment: In a few instances I've migrated it to the other site and flagged it over there as the true-dupe it is.

Comment: You totally got this, but just to emphasize it in case anyone isn't clear: *DO NOT MIGRATE CRAP!!*

Answer (score 1):

If it is worth migrating, I usually do and then flag on the target site telling mods there that its a 100% dupe and needs to be merged, and provide the link to the other copy of the question.